# How can I save over or remove default GoDaddy name servers?

Tags: godaddy, nameserver

Why the default name servers (domaincontrol.com) do not go away with GoDaddy and there seems to be no visible options to edit or remove.

[image: Why the default name servers do not go away with GoDaddy and no visible options to edit or remove.]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like Godaddy specific question & they have detailed guide on how to change Name Servers in Godaddy domain portal in following link.

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664